# Software or site can be affected if the engine of a MySQL table is changed from MySAM to InnoDB?

Tags: mysql, innodb

I know the answer to this may be an absolute NO!. But just to double check, if you have linked several programs to different MySQL tables that are currently using MySAM engine, and then I change the engine to InnoDB, should that affect anything outside the database?, like being unable to retrieve data, insert data, call a stored procedure, etc.

Software can be on different languages, like PHP, JAVA, Visual Fox, .Net, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple dozen differences to consider when switching from MyISAM to InnoDB.  They are [enumerated here](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb).

As you say, the answer is "No".  But, there could be things that leak out of MySQL back to the client.  `FULLTEXT` does not work quite the same.  In some cases, you can get 0 results with InnoDB but not with MyISAM.  Some things can take longer, especially if you did not tweak the indexes as indicated in the link, above.  `LOCK TABLES` should be replaced by `BEGIN` (etc); this involves client code.  The disk space for InnoDB is noticeably bigger.

Yes, `key_buffer_size` should be lowered to, say, 40M; `innodb_buffer_pool_size` should be set to about 70% of available RAM.  This is a big performance issue.

Comment: Can you present a case where I can get 0 results using InnoDB?, FULLTEXT is also available in InnoDB starting from version 5.6 of MySQL according to what i've read. The buffer_pool_size should not be a huge problem or performance issue if the server has 16 to 32 GB of RAM, I can use 50% of available RAM, since most of Query's are around 512KB's ish. Problem is with big Query's that lock the table when are being executed due to MySAM engine.

Comment: Something like `AGAINST('+a +picture')` -- MyISAM will ignore the "short" `a`; InnoDB will see that `a` is not in the index and return 0 results.  The workaround:  Remove "short" words while adding the `+`.  The list of diffs I know about are in http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb

Answer (score 1):

No.
The only thing you should check - is there anything in code that can create tables and have a direct instruction of the engine (something like ENGINE=MyISAM).

ADD: and ofc official manual http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/converting-tables-to-innodb.html

Comment: But that would be in the case of a table reconstruction or something similar correct?. Creating temporary tables as well. But in this case, if I change the default engine of the database to InnoDB, if the code sends the creation of a new table, the new table should be created using InnoDB, this is in the case that the code doesn't specify the engine already like you said, correct?.

Comment: Usually all you need - alter table <> Engine = InnoDB;
But, if you have something in code that have a direct instruction of what engine it must use - it can be more complicated.
And as it said in manual - you will need to edit my.cnf for memory and other InnoDB tuning

Comment: or specify it on the database, in case is not placed on the code itself.

Comment: As an example, if there will be not enough memory (pool_size) in some heavy operations like dump restore HDD can be used so intensive, that server can become unreachable, because ssh/system login timeout.

Comment: but this InnoDB tuning will have to be made on the database too.

Comment: No, for InnoDB all you need is to tune my.cnf (a lot of things ofc you can make w/o restarting with setting variables, etc, but better configure my.cnf one time), it will affect all InnoDB databases.
In fact, after InnoDB as a default engine MySql will use MyISAM after it only for it's internal needs - such as if there will be non enough memory - it will create temporary MyISAM table.

Comment: I understand, but what I am saying is, this file my.cnf is for the database as well, it does not have to be made to the software using the database.

Comment: You can _probably_ get away without changing _client_ code.  The 2-part PK of MyISAM does not exist in InnoDB.  `LOCK TABLES` _should_ be changed.  Certain index changes may be necessary for _performance_.  Etc.

Comment: `CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE` can be any engine you want.  OTOH, a "temporary" table created implicitly by a complex `SELECT` is handled in an engine-independent manner, and will be either `MEMORY` or `MyISAM`, as needed.  (5.8, or so, will change that to InnoDB.)